# Woocommerce Rest API: woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

> Woocommerce version: 4.1.0

I am trying to create a product with categories and images via the API but I get this error :

> {"code":"woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id","message":"#0 is an invalid image ID.","data":{"status":400}}

I have checked some answers but I use image extension in the url, I use only the url not the id and I am not using W3 Cache plugin. Here is the images array of the request:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.domainzzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/MB-150x150.jpg
                    [1] => 150
                    [2] => 150
                    [3] => 1
                )

            [position] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.domainzzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/MG_2072-copy.png
            [position] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.domainzzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/MG_2071-copy.png
            [position] => 2
        )

)
```

And this is the full request:

```
$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://newdomain.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'ck_306dd02a04f81cc33df:cs_4b3c7be0a0' )
        ],
        'body' => [
            'name' => $product->get_name(), // product title
            'slug' => $product->get_slug(),
            'sku' => $product->get_sku(),
            'description' => $product->get_description(),
            'status' => get_post_status($post_id), // product status, default: publish
            'categories' => $cat_ids,
            'images' => $images,
            'regular_price' => $product->get_price() // product price
            // more params http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#product-properties
        ]
    ] );
```

**EDIT**
Here is the code that produces the categories and images arrays:

```
$product = wc_get_product($post_id);

    //Get the categories of the product
    $product_cats_ids = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    $cat_ids = [];
    $images =[];

    foreach( $product_cats_ids as $pci){
        array_push($cat_ids, ['id' => $pci]);
    }

    //IMAGES

    //Get the featured image
    $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));
    //and push it in the images array with position = 0 (featured)
    array_push($images, [$featured_image_url, 'position' => 0]);
    //Get All the images
    $attachmentIds = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    $pos = 1;


    foreach( $attachmentIds as $attachmentId )
    {   
        array_push($images, [wp_get_attachment_url( $attachmentId ), 'position' => $pos]);
        $pos++;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't included the code that defined `$images`, which seems relevant/

Comment: @JacobPeattie you are right! I included the code snippet

Comment: The documentation shows that the image URL needs to have a `src` key: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties